# Edit table of contents [book]

Tags: table-of-contents, books, subfiles

I'd like to edit the table of contents for a `book`-class file. The problem that I'm facing is that I have a lot of separate Chapters, with no sections, in the first part of the book. If I just use `\tableofcontents` it looks like this:

```
I Part
1. Chapter
   1.1 Section
II Part
   2. Chapter
```

etc.
which is generally fine, but since I have a lot of chapters it looks somewhat ugly. I'd would like something like this

```
I Part
   I.1. Chapter
     I.1.1 Section
   I.2. Chapter

II Part
   II.1. Chapter
```

but I honestly have no idea how to realize that. I'll also add an example code here, since I'm not sure if there could be a problem with the `subfile`-package

```
\documentclass[a4paper, leqno, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath, amsthm,mathtools,latexsym}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}
\subfile{Preface.tex}
\tableofcontents
\subfile{Part1.tex}
\subfile{Part2.tex}
\subfile{Part3.tex}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\thepart.\arabic{chapter}}` and this is a clear duplicate of some question (I have to find it, however). Do you really need `latexsym`? I don't think so...

Comment: First of all, thanks. I didn't finde a good answer to the question and your suggestion didn't really word for me ( https://imgur.com/a/qINxiXe , the text and numbers start overlapping). I'm sure there is a way to get this exactly like in my example above... I just don't know how.. And no, I don't need `latexsym`

Comment: The overlapping is a a consequence, true, but that doesn't mean that it is not working. But you got an answer already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to include the part number into the numbering scheme of chapters, sections,... and change the spacing in the table of contents you can use the `tocloft` package as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, leqno, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\thepart.\arabic{chapter}}
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{2em}
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{4em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{6em}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2em}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{3em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{4em}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{one}
\chapter{first chapter}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\chapter{second chapter}
\end{document}
```

`\cft...indent` controls the indentation from the left margin, while `\cft...numwidth` controls the space that can be occupied by the numbers. You can of course adjust them to suit your needs.

[image]